# how to get content in a div without specific child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phantomjs

```
<div class="news"> 
    i need this content

   <figure class="summary">
     i dont need this content
    </figure>

 </div>
```

I want to get "i need this content" in class `.news` but without "i dont need this content" in class `.summary`

```
$("div.news").not("figure.summary").text()
```

I tried this jquery but still gettiing text in figure tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
alert($("div.news").contents().not("figure.summary").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news"> 
    i need this content

   <figure class="summary">
     i dont need this content
    </figure>

 </div>
```

You should use `contents()` to include textNodes:

```
$("div.news").contents().not("figure.summary").text()
```

And if you want to get only textNodes, not filtering out by specific class, type, etc...:

```
$("div.news").contents().not("div.news *").text()
```

Learn more about `.contents()` at: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch text nodes using [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), then you can [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) them and perform desired operation.

```js
var text = $('.news').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

snippet.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  i need this content

  <figure class="summary">
    i dont need this content
  </figure>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
var element = $(".news");
element = element.children().remove();
var text = element.html();
```

First take parent element in a variable:

```
var element = $(".news");
```

Remove children form parent:

```
element = element.children().remove();
```

Now read form parent:

```
var text = element.html();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="news"> 
    <span class="content">i need this content</span>

   <figure class="summary">
     i dont need this content
    </figure>

 </div>
```

and then:

```
$(".content").text();
```

Comment: but there is no span class there. Html is not mine i am getting from web

Answer (score -1):

```
HTMLDivElement HDEMI =(HTMLDivElement)myHTMLDocument.getElementByName("news");
Out_OutputMemberID = Convert.ToString(
                      ((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)(HDEMI.firstChild).nodevalue);
```